# How format datacoming firebase and using snycfusion in PDF

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage, syncfusion

I have data coming from Firebase storage that I put in a table in using plugin  syncfusion datagrid futter table. when I export to PDF with a plugin syncfusion flutter datagrid export, this data cannot be manipulated. please what to do?

here is a function who export in pdf and save:

```
Future<void> exportDataGridToPdf() async {
  final PdfDocument document = _key.currentState!.exportToPdfDocument();

  final List<int> bytes = document.saveSync();

  final Uint8List uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(bytes);

  final Blob blob = Blob([uint8List], 'application/pdf');

  final AnchorElement anchor =
      AnchorElement(href: Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob))
        ..style.display = 'none'
        ..target = 'blank'
        ..download = 'AmbassadeursImperialistes.pdf';

  anchor.click();

  Url.revokeObjectUrl(anchor.href!);
}
```

Comment: What issue have you faced? It appears there is no issue with the download code. If possible, please share the DataGrid configuration code.

Comment: I will rephrase my question: I have a table which shows the statistics for the month with the columns: products, total sales, quantity, commission paid, commission unpaid. in principle the data must be readable in the pdf file, for example on one line it must display (anana,1000,3,15,15) but it is displayed like this ({product: Instance of 'minified:cy', total_sales: 0, quantity: 0, sales: []}
) . do you understand my problem now?